# appcelerator titanium whatsapp share "The item connat be shared,please select a different item"

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

is there a way to share a text on whatsapp with Titanium iOS mobile?
i tried dk.napp.social module it working fine for the image but for text share it gave me an error "The item connat be shared,please select a different item".

any idea thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

iOS 9 has security, add in tiapp.xml

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>whatsapp</string>
</array>
```

and try:

```
var whatsappMessage = String.format('whatsapp://send?text=%s', message);

if(OS_IOS && Ti.Platform.canOpenURL(whatsappMessage)){
   Ti.Platform.openURL(whatsappMessage);
}
```